# Webdriver - Find first x elements with same class

Tags: java, webdriver

Can someone help me in following issue:
I have page with a lot of **li** elements, as shown below:

```
<ul class="feed-tips" id="Grid" data-sport="" data-country="" data-league="">
<li class="feed-item vevent tip-list-row" data-sort-bookmaker="12" data-sort-datetime="1525849200" data-sort-match="1" data-sort-odds="1.80" data-sort-rating="3" data-sort-status="1" data-sort-yield="-2.106" data-tip-id="6900510">
<li class="feed-item vevent tip-list-row" data-sort-bookmaker="22" data-sort-datetime="1525852800" data-sort-match="2" data-sort-odds="2.59" data-sort-rating="2" data-sort-status="1" data-sort-yield="-3.082" data-tip-id="6900483">
<li class="feed-item vevent tip-list-row" data-sort-bookmaker="22" data-sort-datetime="1525852800" data-sort-match="3" data-sort-odds="2.21" data-sort-rating="2" data-sort-status="1" data-sort-yield="-4.118" data-tip-id="6899865">
```

Inside that **li** list each element has following class:

```
<span class="original-language-image flag-icon flag-icon-gb"</span>
```

All **li** elements have that **span** class, and only difference is instead above shown **-gb**, it is different country code.

I have to find first **n** elements with same **gb** code (and also those elements has to be one after another), and compare if is same as first element. Rest with different code, I do not need.

Tried with following code but did something wrong (or made mistake by using **equals** in **if** statement):

```
List<WebElement> tipsGB = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='feed-tips']/li/div[@class='author medium-3 small-12 column padding-reset tip-list-row__author']\n"
            + "//div[@class='original-tip-language-container']/span[contains(@class,'flag-icon-gb')]"));
    WebElement firstTip = tipsGB.get(0);
    for (int p = 1; p < tipsGB.size(); p++) {
        System.out.println(tipsGB.get(p));
        WebElement nextTip = tipsGB.get(p);
        if (nextTip.equals(firstTip)) {
            WebElement tipLink = nextTip.findElement(By.xpath("../../../..\n"
                    + "/div[@class='tip medium-9 small-12 column padding-reset dtstart tip-list-row__tip']\n"
                    + "/div[@class='tip-match medium-12 column']/div[@class='tip-teams']/a"));
            System.out.println("Link to a tip with same language is: " + tipLink.getAttribute("href"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No more tips in same language on top of page");
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the following scenario :**

**1**.Select all elements whose class contain the term **'flag-icon-gb'**. ( You can restrict the search to one kind of element by replacing the * above.
For example to search for all li, you would put //li[...]

**2**. Iterate over your list to manipulate the first **n** elements you wish.

**3**.Do what you want for each element inside the loop (compare, get childrens, click, etc,...)

```
//Get all flags containing GB
List<WebElement> tipsGB = driver.findElements((By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,\'flag-icon-gb\')]"))

//Iterate over the list and do your stuff

for(int i=0; i<numberofElementsYouWant<;i++){

  Webelement currentElement = tipsGB.get(i);
  //manipulate your elements here
  currentElement.Dostuff();

}
```

**Edit :** it seems that your problem is relative to the comparaison.
You are trying to compare Objects (WebElements) and those don't aren't equal.Only their texts are.
Try like so instead :

```
String firstTip = tipsGB.get(0).getAttribute("data-tip-id");
```

Do the same then inside the loop and then compare

```
String nextTip = tipsGB.get(p).getAttribute("data-tip-id");
if (nextTip.equals(firstTip)) {
....
}
```

Comment: Your path to a list is shorter, but I already find all elements with containing class. My  confusion is why when I choose first element (with index = 0) and when try to compare it with next one, it does not works. Tried with if . zero-element.equals. to-next (through iteration)

Comment: I think the error is related to the comparaison of objects instead of text, i edited my answer.